What would be the best strategy if you need to partition a table by a field, but the resulting number of partitions exceeds the limit?
Ok, so I have the following case:
I am using incremental strategy (using dbt and airflow) to feed data to a BigQuery table, BigQuery has a limit of 10,000 partitions, so I have the table partitioned by date and clustered by account.
The thing is that this performs well when it comes to increasingly adding data several times a day, but for example, if I needed to bring historic data for a certain account I have to re-create the whole table. I think that this could be better if I could partition the table by accounts, but there are like more than 50k accounts.
Is there a sharding or merging strategy or something else that I could follow given this scenario? Are there best practices when it comes to cases like this in BigQuery?

I'm not following your story ... you say "If I need to bring historic data for a certain account I have to re-create the whole table".  Can you flesh this out some more?  Generically, the purpose of partitioning is to prune the amount of data to be scanned ... maybe create bucketed column ... for example if you had a deterministic function hash(account) that returned an integer between 0 at 9999 you could map your account to a partition

@Kolban The table is already partitioned by date (monthly), but if a new account is added with all its historic data from years ago then I have to recreate the whole table (I am using insert_overwrite in dbt to overwrite partitions), instead of just incrementally adding a new account, so partitioning by account would be optimal for me, but there are way more accounts than partitions available. I think what you say about hashing and mapping the account to a partition might be the solution I am looking for

At load time, synthesize a column that holds a partial account id that fits within the partition limit.
For example: if account_id is a number in the range 100,000 to 150,000, divide it to give ~10K values such as (account_id / 5) as account_set. That will give you values with the range 20,000 to 30,000.
Not, if you have non-numeric account_ids, this will require a deterministic mapping to a numeric value for the account_set.
Create your table as:
CREATE TABLE account_data (..., account_id, account_set, ...)
PARTITION BY account_set
CLUSTER BY account_set, account_id

When you query, specify the account_set and account_id in the predicate. BigQuery will select the partition using the account_set and use the account_set, account_id to select the subset of records from the partition.
One caveat is partition_expiration_days will affect all accounts that fall in that partition. You'll need a different approach if you need to expire data.
